# Firebase cross domain javascript authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am implementing a bookmarking service (think Instapaper) using Firebase as a back end. Mostly it's working great, however I'm running into one major problem.

A core part of the service will be a bookmarklet that allows users to bookmark pages they are currently viewing in their browser (again, like Instapaper's: https://www.instapaper.com/save).

The first problem I encountered when implementing this was that even when a user is logged in on my firebaseapp.com page, that user was not showing up as authenticated when the javascript from the bookmarklet was fired. I figured out this was most likely due to cross-domain issues, so I next implemented an iframe-based solution. The idea being that the url of the iframe is hosted on my firebaseapp.com site, allowing the currently-logged-in user to show up as authenticated.

This works great in Chrome and Firefox but fails in Safari when the security setting for cookies and website data is set to "Allow from websites I visit" rather than "Always allow" (asking users to switch that setting to "Always allow" is not practical).

Is there any solution to this problem? Forcing users to log in every time the bookmarklet is clicked on a new domain would be highly inconvenient. I'm basically out of ideas at this point (and starting to get out of my depth on the web dev side of things).

Thank you so much for any help!